# Conventions for using std::feclearexcept

Tags: c++, exception, error-handling, floating-point

Is there any convention for using `std::feclearexcept`? In the examples you usually see, this is called **before** an operation is executed that might trigger a floating point exception. This seems a safe thing to do.

But should you also call `std::feclearexcept` **after** you have detected and handled an error, so that the error state does not persist throughout the rest of the program's execution?

If you would always call `std::feclearexcept` before checking for floating point exceptions, and if you would always check all operations that could trigger such exceptions, then this would be redundant. But these are a lot of ifs and an unlikely situation in real software, at least from my experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simlar in reasoning to (re-)setting `errno` only before you do a specific operation and intend to check `errno` afterwards.

There might be conditions under which `errno`, or the floating point exception flags, are set that you are not aware of. You don't know where exactly they happened or what they mean semantically. You are not equipped to handle a situation of "uh, there was an overflow somewhere in the past but I don't know what it means".

Thus, you reset `errno` / call `std::feclearexcept` right before you execute a specific operation where you *want* to know the exact result / error condition, and *do* know how to handle it.

Resetting the error flags after that operation serves no purpose.

Comment: Since a function set may be used underneath higher level code, would you see saving the error state, clear the state, perform your operations, handle errors then restore the state?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: (That first reply was a desaster. Sorry if you had to read through that. :-D ) The contents of `errno` are good until the next call to a standard library function, so the only level at which that clear - restore routine makes sense is *in the standard library itself*. (7.5 footnote 202)) Higher-level code cannot, and should not, assume that some (possibly third-party) lower layer does *not* make a call to a standard library function (trashing the contents of `errno`). You clear `errno` immediately before you call e.g. `strtol()`, then check it immediately afterwards.

Comment: (ctd.) WIth `<fenv.h>` / `<cfenv>`, the wording is a bit different, but the mechanism is the same: Any standard library function, or indeed any arithmetic operation on floating point values, can set any of those flags in your FENV state. High-level code expecting information from such a noisy channel to make it through unspecified lower levels would be poorly designed. Reinstating state after operations of your own happens is something for standard library implementors to worry about, not application developers.

Comment: (ctd. 2) Indeed, who is to say whether the higher level code does not *expect* you to leave the error flags resulting from your operation *set*, because the errors occurred, didn't they? What I am trying to say here is that both `<errno.h>` and `<fenv.h>` only make sense at the lowermost level of code, because they are "noisy channels".

Comment: Fair discussion. I have written libraries that restore `errno` (yes , multi-thread remains an issue) yet have not thought about FP.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: C11 gave `errno` thread-local storage duration... about the only saving grace to this dumpster fire of error reporting channel...